# How do I continuously send integers to the client? And how do i send the amount of clients connected to the client?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, server, client

I am trying to make a multiplayer curve_fever for a school project. Right now, I have a working client-server connection and a working chat box. What i can't figure out is how to send the amount of clients that are connected to all clients. By doing this i can make sure the game waits for the right amount of people. I also can't figure out how to continiously send data from the client to the server and back. So i can see all the coordinates from all the players.

This is my server:

```
public class Server
{
    public TcpListener Listener;
    private volatile bool Running; //wordt gebruikt door meerdere threads zonder lock te gebruiken (lock zorgt ervoor dat een thread niet doorgaat naar belangrijke code terwjil een andere thread nog bezig is om naar de locked code te gaan.
    private List<BinaryWriter> writers = new List<BinaryWriter>();
    public Server(int port)
    {
        Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Listener.Start(10);
        Running = true;

        while (Running)
        {
            var connection = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            ProcessConnection(connection);//Het zal asynchroon werken, omdat we nog niet eerder een beroep hebben geschreven af te wachten
        }
    }


    public async Task ProcessConnection(TcpClient connection)
    { //Het zal worden uitgevoerd in een afzonderlijke thread
        var writer = new BinaryWriter(connection.GetStream());

        lock (writers)
        {
            writers.Add(writer);
        }

        using (var stream = new BinaryReader(connection.GetStream()))
        {
            //loop 
            while (Running && connection.Connected)
            {
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                    var count = stream.ReadInt32();
                    var data = stream.ReadBytes(count);
                    ProcessCommand(connection, writer, data);
                });
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        lock (writers)
        {
            writers.Remove(writer);
        }
    }


    private void ProcessCommand(TcpClient connection, BinaryWriter writer, byte[] data)
    {
        var info = connection.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
        var line = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
        var response = String.Format("{1}:{2}: {0}", line, info.Address.ToString(), info.Port);
        Console.WriteLine(response);
        lock (writers)
        {
            foreach (var w in writers)
            {
                if (w != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        w.Write((Int32)data.Length);
                        w.Write(data);
                        w.Flush();
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void Stop()
    {
        Running = false;
        Listener.Stop();
    }
    ~Server()
    {
        Running = false;
        Listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

Andt his is my client:

```
       public async Task Start(int port)
    {

        Connection.Connect("localhost", port);
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        Running = true;
        Writer = new BinaryWriter(Connection.GetStream());

        using (var stream = new BinaryReader(Connection.GetStream()))
        {
            //infinite loop
            while (Running && Connection.Connected)
            {
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                    var count = stream.ReadInt32();
                    var data = stream.ReadBytes(count);
                    ProcessCommand(data);
                });
            }
            Stop();
        }
    }
    //send data voor chat
    public async Task Send(String line)
    {
        if (Writer == null)
            return;
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            var data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line);
            Writer.Write((Int32)data.Length);
            Writer.Write(data);
            Writer.Flush();
        });
    }
    //krijg het aantal spelers connected

    private void ProcessCommand(byte[] data)
    {
        var line = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        //stuur data van server naar method
        textboxChat(line);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Running = false;
        Writer.Close();
        Writer = null;
        Connection.Close();

    }
    ~GamePlay()
    {
        Stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1st point : count of connected clients :

server-side :

Create a dictionnary that will store info about connected clients.
I would personnally use client IP (or any other identification you have) as key, and client data as value (timestamp of last connection, client coordinates, etc...).

You'll have to update this dictionary at each new connection, and each time a client disconnect / send new data, or when last action is too old.

This way, when sending data to clients, you would be able to send count of Dictionary.KeyValuePair as a number of all connected clients.

Once you are prepared to manage all of this data, you now need to send data to and from client and server.
To do so, make sure you are able to send messages in both direction.

2nd point : continuously sending data back and forth between client and server.

client-side : 
* in the main loop : send messages with data.

- when receiving data from the server : // use data to do whatever you want.

Server-side :
* when receiving data from a client : update data in dictionary, then send it back to all other known clients.

That's how I would do.
Here is another solution : send data back to client as an answer to their own updates
-> When server receive data from client, he answers back with all data from all clients.